# When using group by count in a subquery using python django, an error occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

I am using django 2.2.7, python3.7.9.

```
class FuneralHall(models.Model):
    hall_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    flower_vender = models.ForeignKey('bugo.FlowerVender', default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sales_partner = models.ForeignKey('main.SalesPartner', default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class FlowerOrder(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('init', '결제준비'),
        ('ready', '입금대기'),
        ('paid', '입금완료'),
        ('confirm', '주문확인'),
        ('sent', '배송출발'),
        ('complete', '배송완료'),
        ('cancel', '배송취소'),
        ('refund', '환불'),
    )

    funeral = models.ForeignKey(Funeral, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    funeral_hall = models.ForeignKey(FuneralHall, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    funeral_room = models.ForeignKey(FuneralRoom, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    flower_product = models.ForeignKey(FlowerProduct, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    flower_vender = models.ForeignKey(FlowerVender, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sales_partner = models.ForeignKey(SalesPartner, null=True, blank=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default='init')
```

```
flower_order_count = FlowerOrder.objects.filter(funeral_hall_id=OuterRef('id')).annotate(flower_order_count=Func('funeral_hall_id', function='Count')).values('flower_order_count')

hall_list = FuneralHall.objects.annotate(flower_count=Subquery(flower_order_count))
```

This code works fine.

However, if I add a filter condition to the subquery, an error occurs.

```
flower_order_count = FlowerOrder.objects.filter(funeral_hall_id=OuterRef('id'), order_status='complete').annotate(flower_order_count=Func('funeral_hall_id', function='Count')).values('flower_order_count')

hall_list = FuneralHall.objects.annotate(flower_count=Subquery(flower_order_count))
```

The error is 'Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.' occurs, but output_field doesn't seem to matter.

When using group by count in a subquery, I shouldn't add a condition to the filter. Is there a way to add it?

I've tried adding output_field to the subquery, and I've tried meeting different conditions. All failed to work.